# How do I create a self updating response to a form

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

So I want to use Javascript (AJAX) and PHP/HTML to create a form and update it automatically. I'm trying to create a website that will perform simple mathematical calculations (thinking volume, surface area, and other geometry stuff). Eventually I'd like to have graphical representations, but not yet.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Do I want the form to submit to a web page, which outputs a JSON or XML object, and then use XMLHttp to pull that? Would that be the easiest way? Would I want to use Javascript to prevent me from actually redirecting to that page?

I've used AJAX before once or twice, but only nominally. This is also an exercise in getting myself better acquainted with the technology.

Comment: Why do you need server-side processing at all? Can't you just make calculations in JS? It's going to be a rewarding choice when you'll be dealing with graphics because you can render them in `<canvas>` instead that thru PHP GD.

Comment: I did consider that. I suppose if I don't need any database or backend stuff, I can just use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

For a PHP-developer, a very nice way is to use xAjax, which is [document here](http://www.xajaxproject.org).

Using this PHP code, you **register some functions**:

```
include './xajax/xajax_core/xajax.inc.php';

$xajax = new xajax();

$xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION, 'doAdd');
$xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION, 'doReset');

$xajax->processRequest();
```

Then, you simply use the **registered functions** as **JavaScript methods**:

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">

  <input type="button" onclick="xajax_doAdd(10,600);" id="btnAdd" value="Click Me" />

  <input type="button" onclick="xajax_doReset();" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />

  <p id="answer"></p>

</form>
```